# Check if datatable contains column in crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to show dynamic Crystal Report. While doing so I've encountered a scenario that  `dataset coming from database` doesn't contain the specified column mentioned in the `crystal report typed dataset`.

For example, the dataset coming from the database contains the following columns:

```
col1,col2,col3
```

and the Dataset in the Crystal Report contains the following columns:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
```

I want to check if `col4` is present in the dataset(coming from db) and if it is present I want to assign it in formula field like:

```
If IsNull({DataTable.col4}) then
  "0"
Else
  {DataTable.col4}
```

I've tried the above method but i'm getting the following error like

```
This field name is not known. Details: errorKind
```

Comment: Error iteslf expalins that the column is not available.... but instead of checking `null` you can use `HASValue` to check if the value is preasent

Comment: I tried it but getting an error as `parameterfield is required inside HASValue`